# Javascript frustration dealing with the DOM, what works in 1 spot, doesnt seem to work elsewhere

Tags: javascript, counter, getelementbyid

**PROBLEM**

This works if I take out the comment

```
    //document.getElementById('formtimer').innerHTML = TimeStr; // Shows 00:15:00
```

Works wonderfully.  So, I comment that out and...

I wanted to make a graphical counter so I went into Photoshop and made 0-9 and tried this...

```
var imgCounter = document.getElementById('formtimer');
imgCounter.src = "graphics/odometers/white and blue with black background/1.png";
```

When the 1 was never drawn I put this in the HTML (just in case I had to have a picture already there)...

```
<td class="tbl_col1"><div align="right" id="formtimer"><img src="graphics/odometers/white and blue with black background/0.png" /></div></td>
```

SO... it draws a 0 on the screen, and the javascript should change it to a 1.  I thought the path was incorrect so I played with that.  I even copied the below code from another function (that works) to here - and it didnt work (the original ID for the "other" working code was different.  I changed it to 'formtimer' when I copied it into this non-working script.

```
var img_sad = "graphics/signup/smiley-sad006.gif";
var imgUsername = document.getElementById('formtimer');
imgUsername.src = img_sad;
```

I'm confused why the innerHTML works fine, and my graphics don't work.  I tried debugging in Firebug and no errors appear.

Please and thank you once again!

Comment: I checked your website and the formtimer is a div element, not an img. Could that by why you can't set the image on it?

Comment: There are no spaces allowed in URLs.  I'd suggest you remove them from your image filenames in the first place, but if you insist on having them, then they have to be encoded to `%20` in HTML.

Comment: I'll remove the spaces.  Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to create a separate question for Problem 2.

Comment: Sorry Brian... I didn't mean to waste your time - I know you mentioned checking my site. I appreciate your effort. I spent like 4 hours trying to figure out why it didn't work. And voila. Typing it out on here helped - I found the solution as soon as I looked over at my monitor after spending all this time typing this out on here!  lol.   Maybe I should email myself first in the future! lol. Just kidding.  You were correct tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById('formtimer');` gets the `<div>` element and `imgCounter.src = "..."` sets the src attribute of the `<div>`, which has no meaning.

You should get the `<img>` element instead. You can do this using the `firstChild` property or adding an id to the `<img>` element.

Comment: Thank you.  I did find the mistake and tried answering part 1 myself (after 4 hours of trying, I found it after posting it on here lol).  You are also correct.  2 people found the problem in seconds.  Superior web development skills than mine :) lol  Can you explain how to add multiple images together or do I need to have multiple ID's to string  3 pictures together like 123.

Comment: I'm going to create a separate question for problem 2.